# How to apply different conditions to join, bases a columns value in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

Am having a data as below

Table emp

| Cty | name | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | aa | na |
| Gua | bb | city |

Table city

| Id | city | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new york | aa |
| 2 | ohio | bb |

I want to apply join based on flag columns value in single query.

Such as when flag is NA

`flag='na' then emp.name=city.name`

`flag='City' then emp.name=city.name and emp.cty=city.city`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
JOIN CITY ON emp.name=city.name
and  (emp.flag='na' or emp.flag='city' and emp.cty=city.city)
```